# Why declare a 'Image' variable and then assign value occurs errors?

Tags: java, declare

I meet a wired problem in java ,below codes shows errors :

```
public class GameStart extends GameFrame {


    Image plane1=null;

    plane1=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\jack\\IdeaProjects\\Selftest\\Game\\src\\plane.png"));

................
```

while such below codes is normal , i dont know why ,cause both of them is the same meaning ,the only difference is the declaration order itself , is there any wrong matter with my code?

```
public class GameStart extends GameFrame {

    Image plane1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\jack\\IdeaProjects\\Selftest\\Game\\src\\plane.png"));

...................
```

[image: Error occurance]

[image: Normal situation]

Comment: I am new to java , Thanks if you can help me !

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which error are you talking about? In general, you should not use `null` if possible. If you can, properly initialized variables while declaring them.

Comment: When you not directly initialize your field (one line), you must do it in a constructor, method or "{...}" block..... but you do it out of nowhere in a class that is not possible. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: @cbley The red underline warning is my concerned error, idle said "plane1" is unknow class ,but i have declared it in "Image" class beforehand

Comment: what error you got? Image is an abstract class and cannot be directly initialized...but the null-assignment should normally work.

Comment: The answer you're looking for is in the comment by @pL4Gu33

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Yes , you are right , this is a real detail i have noticed before , thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking it's the IDE you're using, whether it's Eclipse or IntelliJ, etc. It's probably not refreshing properly.

A better test would be to compile the two differences from the command line with javac. They should both compile without errors.

This probably should have been a comment but I don't have enough reputation points, I'm getting there uggghh.

Comment: No , it is not the matter of idle , though i use Clion , the solution comes from comments below that original question , you can refer to it if you have interest .